# Copying from raw pointer to smart pointer using memcpy

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am trying to convert a legacy C code to use smart pointers. And came across the following (just snippets to get me started):

```
MATRIX* cache;
---
cache = new MATRIX[numRow*numCol];
if (cache == NULL) 
{
    return FAIL;
}
---
memset(cache, 0, sizeof(MATRIX)*numRow*numCol);
---
memcpy(cache, matrix, sizeof(MATRIX)*numRow*numCol);
```

I tried to convert them to become like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<MATRIX[]> cache;
---
cache = std::make_unique<MATRIX[]>(numRow*numCol);
if (cache == NULL) 
{
    return FAIL;
}
---
cache.reset();
```

Is this correct? Any better way to write it? Also, I'm not sure how to do the `memcpy` C++ counterpart of

```
memcpy(cache, matrix, sizeof(MATRIX)*numRow*numCol);
```

`matrix` is just a raw pointer of type MATRIX*.
Any suggestions?? Thank you so much!

Comment: The C++ counterpart of `memcpy` is called `std::copy`.

Comment: Also, you should not do `cache.reset()` explicitly. The memory is freed automatically when `cache`'s destructor is called.

Comment: You could make this a single line : `std::unique_ptr<Matrix[]> cache{new Matrix[numRow*numCol]}`

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `std::vector<MATRIX>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your implementation is correct, but you don't have to call `reset` to do the cleanup of the memory. It will be handled automatically by the `std::unique_ptr` class, and to access unique pointer memory we can just use `get` method like the following:

```
cache.get();
```

Hence, your `memcpy` will look like

```
memcpy(cache.get(), matrix, sizeof(MATRIX)*numRow*numCol);
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is working! :) Just one question though.  Do you think this code is still necessary? ```if (cache == NULL) 
{
    return FAIL;
}```  Or should I already remove it since it was called right after creation of the ```unique_ptr```?

Comment: `make_unique` throws an exception when allocation failed, it calls `new` operator. The code `cache == NULL` will never execute, you should remove it. Also use `nullptr`, not `NULL`.

Comment: @Kay, as suggested by Kamil, you need not to write ``cache == NULL``, but you can enclose ``cache = std::make_unique<MATRIX[]>(numRow*numCol);`` inside of ``try{...}catch`` to catch ``std::bad_alloc``.